# MVVM + Kotlin - binding

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, binding

Изучаю MVVM. Ранее не работал с этим. В тех примерах, что я встретил - везде используется binding, но это устаревшая библиотека (в случае, если вы пишите на Kotlin она просто не нужна). Можно ли выполнить MVVM реализацию без binding? Или же данный паттерн работает строго с binding?

Comment: Я бы не торопился с выводами об устаревании Binding, хоть и сам ею не пользуюсь. На последнем IO о ней много рассказывали, не суть Kotlin или Java в проекте. Вот ButterKnife да, уже не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Android jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/), в частности [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), вероятно это то, что Вы ищете.

Answer (score -1):

Полагаю, мне удалось кое-что найти, хотя решения хуже binding честно слово... Крутая самопальщщина. Идея заключается в том, чтобы использовать rx-java вместо binding для передачи и обновления параметров. Вот две статьи на эту тему:
https://medium.com/corebuild-software/simple-android-mvvm-using-rx-and-kotlin-9769a91b03ef

https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c